# Basic survey app

Tags: c#, mvc, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am learning MVC 5 .NET and this is a bit different than Rails activerecord when creating relations. I have created a basic survey app that has a Survey class and this relates to the questions and answers. When I create the survey I want to create a few questions to go with the survey.

Would this be the best way to handle the relation for the survey if I pass a set of questions to the controller? I just want to know if I am doing anything wrong since none of my peers know MVC.

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(FormCollection QuestionList)
{

    Survey survey = new Survey();
    foreach (var item in QuestionList.AllKeys)
    {
        if (item != "__RequestVerificationToken")
        {
            Question question = new Question();
            question.SurveyQuestion = QuestionList[item].ToString();
            question.Survey = survey;                    
            db.Questions.Add(question);
        }

    }
    db.SaveChanges();
    return View();
}
```

**Models**

```
public class Survey
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Question> Questions { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
}

public class Question
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string SurveyQuestion { get; set; }
        public int SurveyId { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
        public virtual Survey Survey { get; set; }
    }

public class Answer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
    public int SurveyId { get; set; }

    public virtual Question Question { get; set; }
    public virtual Survey Survey { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it works it ain't wrong... but there's always space to improve.

My main concern would be that you're not using an explicit type-mapping when posting to the controller, but instead you use the anonymous FormCollection.

Why not just post an IEnumerable to the controller? Then you can let MVC bind the model for you...

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(IEnumerable<Question> questionList)
    {

        Survey survey = new Survey();
        foreach (var item in questionList)
        {
             Question question = new Question();
             question.SurveyQuestion = item;
             question.Survey = survey;                    
             db.Questions.Add(question);
        }
        db.SaveChanges();
        return View();
    }
```

You also might want to Add the Survey to the Database, or look up an existing one.

Comment: I did not think of using the IEnumerable. Good Idea. Thanks. As for the Survey part I thought I was doing that when I created the new Instance and then add it to the Questions.

Comment: Well if the Survey gets persisted through the relationship anyway, there's no need to change anything. I wasn't sure how EntityFramework would behave, this is more a just-in-case thing. In my code, I'd always persist the Survey first just to be sure the database will accept the Questions. But that might be overly cautious.

Comment: Yeah this is good stuff. Thank you I like the suggestions. The code looks better and it now I should be able to create the dynamic fields I want down the row.

Answer (score 1):

Don't call things `SomeClassList` etc. Instead of `QuestionList`, name it `questions` (camelCase because that is the standard for parameters).

---

Also, don't call things `item` when they're something specific: `foreach (var item in QuestionList.AllKeys)`. In this case it's a `key`, and if you're using ckonig's code -- `foreach (var item in questionList)` -- it should be `foreach (var question in questions)`.

---

While we're on the topic of ckonig's code, I'm a bit baffled by the parameter being `IEnumerable<Question>` and yet in the `foreach` a new `Question` is created. I would be careful to expose database entities like that, I'm more in favor of exposing [DTOs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649585.aspx).

---

This can be written much simpler:

```
Question question = new Question();
question.SurveyQuestion = QuestionList[item].ToString();
question.Survey = survey;
```

Compare with:

```
var question = new Question
{
   SurveyQuestion = QuestionList[item].ToString(),
   Survey = survey
};
```

This is the cleaner, more modern way.

---

I would also urge you to separate your concerns into layers. Right here you have a `db` in your controller and that's a bad practice (yes, I know, Microsoft also does it but their example code is unfortunately often not following accepted best practices). Look into introducing [a Service layer](http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/asp-net-mvc-moving-code-from-controller-action-to-service-layer), for instance. Here's [another example](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/135751/123339) (though I'd avoid the Repository when working with Entity Framework).